# Convergence of $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$ and $g_{n}(x)=\frac{2nx}{x^2+n^2}$ in sup norm

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I need to show that

(i) $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$ converges to the zero function in sup norm, and

(ii) $g_{n}(x)=\frac{2nx}{x^2+n^2}$ does not.

Not sure if this is right but would appreciate any corrections/direction.

For part (i), I need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $O(0,\epsilon)$ contains all points $f_{n}(x)$ with $n>N_{\epsilon}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Also, let $N_{\epsilon}\in{\mathbb{N}}$ where $N_{\epsilon}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}-x^2}$. Then for every $n>{N_{\epsilon}}$ such that $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$, $|f_{n}(x)-0|\leq{\sup|f_{n}(x)-0|}\leq{|\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}-0|}=\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}<\frac{1}{x^2+N_{\epsilon}^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}-x^2})^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{\epsilon}-x^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon.$

...

For part (ii), I need to show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N_{\epsilon}\in{\mathbb{N}}$, there exists $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $n>N_{\epsilon}$ and $d(g_{n}(x),g_{N_{\epsilon}}(x))\geq{\epsilon}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Consider $|g_{n}(x)-g_{N_{\epsilon}}(x)|=|\frac{2nx}{x^2+n^2}-\frac{2N_{\epsilon}x}{x^2+N_{\epsilon}^2}|$. I am not sure what to let $n$ or $N_{\epsilon}$ be to where $d(g_{n}(x),g_{N_{\epsilon}}(x))\geq{\epsilon}$.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

You can answer the two questions on a simple way:

- The sequence $(f_n)_n$ is componentwise convergent to the zero function so it suffices to show that this convergence is uniform by this inequality
  $$|f_n(x)|\le \frac 1 {n^2},\forall x\in \Bbb R$$
- The sequence $(g_n)_n$ is componentwise convergent to the zero function but the convergence isn't uniform since
  $$|g_n(n)|=1\not\rightarrow0$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for part (i), you need to choose $N_\epsilon$ which is independent of $x$ (Well, just use $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - x^2} < \sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$.)

For part (ii), consider $g_n(n)$.